# How to prevent php submission of sms text message on page refresh?

Tags: php, sms, page-refresh

I am using a 3rd party sms gateway to send clients a text message when a prospect submits an inquiry form on their web page. I'm using Aweber for the autoresponder system, who sends a query string with the prospect data in it, which I collect and send to the client, along with a text message to his cell phone.

I have everything working. However, I need to prevent the client from receiving multiple text messages from the same prospect within that same session, caused by refreshing or hitting the BACK button on the browser.

Here is the code I'm using, which is working, except for this issue:

```
   $name      = $_GET['name'];
   $email     = $_GET['email'];
   $address   = $_GET['address'];
   $phone     = $_GET['phone'];
   $phone_sms = preg_replace('/^1|\D/', "", $phone);

   $message   = "$name, $email, just submitted an inquiry for $address";

   $from      = "1212121212";   // Ph# txt message is received from
   $to        = "$phone_sms";   // Ph# txt message is sent to

   $url       = 'http://domain.com/of/api';

   $fields = array(
     'from'     =>urlencode($from),
     'to'       =>urlencode($to),
     'message'  =>urlencode($message),
   );

   foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
   rtrim($fields_string,'&');

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: just wanted to know which 3rd party sms gateway you are using?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar The above code is for Sourcesms (out of UK), which works fine. But I have found a more robust gateway (Twilio) with greater reliability, support, and an extensive amount of resources for a much less cost in the US. I am testing their system out now, and it seems to be working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send a `Location` header to redirect to a "success" page at the end of the script you posted, the back button will not load the page twice.

Try:

```
// ... your code from the question
curl_close($ch);

header('Location: /sent.php');
exit;
```

Then have `sent.php` show the confirmation page letting them know their message was sent.  If you need to send specific data from their request, add it to a session prior to redirecting and read that data from the session on `sent.php`.

By sending the redirect, the browser will NOT attempt to re-post the same data again when using the back button to navigate.  It will also prevent a refresh of the page (after sending the form) from trying to re-post the data again.

Comment: @user1322707 I would suggest this sort of approach to all form submissions. It takes the *stupid* away from the user and stops them being able to mess up your site functionality. +1 (when I get my votes back shortly)

Comment: @ drew010 duhhh! I don't know what I was thinking ;) Thanks for the PHP 101 instruction that flew right past me :-/

Comment: IRT Fluffeh's comment, I agree and I use this same method for all form submissions as well.  Using this solves a lot of those back button issues when it comes to form posts.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make it cookie based?

so basically

```
if(cookie =='') { /*do the stuff - AND set the cookie*/}

if(cookie !=='') { /* don't do the stuff */ }
```